# Missing dependencies for an example of using policies in StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am trying to get [example 2](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/policies/) of how to use policies in StructureMap working. I have created a small test-project (code below). Unfortunately for some reason there seem to be some dependency issues, since the `.As<type>` and `.Each` are both not working.

For the lines using `As` such as

```
user.Green.As<Database>().ConnectionString.ShouldBe("*green*");
```

I am getting the error:

> 'IDatabase' does not contain a definition for 'As' and no extension method 'As' accepting a first argument of type 'IDatabase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?). And for this line:

```
instance.Constructor.GetParameters()
                .Where(x => x.ParameterType == typeof(IDatabase))
                .Each(param => ...
```

> 'StringExtensions.Each(IEnumerable, Action)' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

I installed StructureMap 4.2 using NuGet. As you can see in the code below, I put in all the `using`-statements from StructureMap, that I could find, but I am still having the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Pipeline;
using StructureMap.Pipeline.Lazy;
using StructureMap.Configuration;
using StructureMap.Building;
using StructureMap.Attributes;
using StructureMap.AutoMocking;
using StructureMap.Graph;
using StructureMap.Query;
using StructureMap.TypeRules;
using StructureMap.Util;
using StructureMap.Building.Interception;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using StructureMap.Diagnostics.TreeView;
using StructureMap.Graph.Scanning;

namespace TestStructureMapPolicies
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new Container(_ =>
            {
                _.For<IDatabase>().Add<Database>().Named("red")
                    .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("*red*");

                _.For<IDatabase>().Add<Database>().Named("green")
                    .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("*green*");

                _.Policies.Add<InjectDatabaseByName>();
            });


            // ImportantService should get the "red" database
            container.GetInstance<ImportantService>()
                .DB.As<Database>().ConnectionString.ShouldBe("*red*");

            // BigService should get the "green" database
            container.GetInstance<BigService>()
                .DB.As<Database>().ConnectionString.ShouldBe("*green*");

            // DoubleDatabaseUser gets both
            var user = container.GetInstance<DoubleDatabaseUser>();

            user.Green.As<Database>().ConnectionString.ShouldBe("*green*");
            user.Red.As<Database>().ConnectionString.ShouldBe("*red*");

        }
    }

    public interface IDatabase { }

    public class Database : IDatabase
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        public Database(string connectionString)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("ConnectionString: {0}", ConnectionString);
        }
    }

    public class InjectDatabaseByName : ConfiguredInstancePolicy
    {
        protected override void apply(Type pluginType, IConfiguredInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Constructor.GetParameters()
                .Where(x => x.ParameterType == typeof(IDatabase))
                .Each(param =>
                {
                        // Using ReferencedInstance here tells StructureMap
                        // to "use the IDatabase by this name"
                        var db = new ReferencedInstance(param.Name);
                    instance.Dependencies.AddForConstructorParameter(param, db);
                });
        }
    }

    public class BigService
    {
        public BigService(IDatabase green)
        {
            DB = green;
        }

        public IDatabase DB { get; set; }
    }

    public class ImportantService
    {
        public ImportantService(IDatabase red)
        {
            DB = red;
        }

        public IDatabase DB { get; set; }
    }

    public class DoubleDatabaseUser
    {
        public DoubleDatabaseUser(IDatabase red, IDatabase green)
        {
            Red = red;
            Green = green;
        }

        // Watch out for potential conflicts between setters
        // and ctor params. The easiest thing is to just make
        // setters private
        public IDatabase Green { get; private set; }
        public IDatabase Red { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `As<T>()` extension method I used in the tests isn't part of the BCL and that's why you're not finding it. If you're using Shouldly, you could effect the same thing with `ShouldBeOfType<T>()` or just cast it normally before making the comparisons. Same thing with the `Each()` extension.